# Why Statistical significance level is chosen to be 0.05?

Tags: statistics

I am new to data science and statistical inference , Lately I have been working on statistical  hypothesis testing in R and was wondering that why industry standard for significance level is chosen to be 0.05 (for p-value) and not 0.01  ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It signifies a confidence level of 95%.  You say "why not 0.01", and the answer is:  you can use 99% confidence, and sometimes you need to be that sure.  But in most cases 95% is good enough.